# Increment selected part of formatted TimeSpan

Tags: c#, string-formatting, timespan

How do I increment `TimeSpan` value, given its format string and a position(=part) in the formatted value?
In other words, it could be described as following function stub:

```
TimeSpan IncrementTimeSpan(TimeSpan value, string format, int positionInValueString)
{
  Debug.Assert(positionInValueString >= 0 
              && positionInValueString < value.ToString(format).Length);
  //in: 01:00:00 hh:mm:ss pos: 7
  //out: 01:00:01
  //in: 01 days 10:30 dd days hh:mm pos: 1
  //out: 02 days 10:30
  TimeSpan unitToIncrement = FindTheUnitAtPos(value.ToString(format), positionInValueString);
  return value.Add(unitToIncrement);
}
```

Where `positionInValueString` is a position in the `value.ToString(format)` string which is guaranteed to be valid one (i.e. between 0 and `value.ToString(format).Length-1`).
The `format` is not known in compile time but it is guaranteed to be valid one, if the position does not correspond to any unit value in the value string, either of the nearest ones can be incremented. Does not have to handle 12-hour formats.

Comment: How do you figure position 7 in the first sample, when there are only six meaningful characters?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn well, figguring out which characters are meaningful would be big step forward. Without the knowledge `value.ToString(format)`  is just a "01:00:00"  string, where at position 7 is '0'

Comment: To be honest, I think that (ab)using string conversions/representations to achieve Timespan addition is a horrible approach.

Comment: @PeterB It is horrible, but I dont see any other option in GUI. All I know is the format, the string value(or already parsed one) and user caret position. Still, I am convinced it the lesser evil of that and spending weeks on re-writing GUI library from the scratch.

Comment: Your second format `dd days hh:mm` already shows pretty well why this is a bad approach.  The first two `d` are format specifiers. But if the position would lead to the `d` from `days` it would be treated as one even if it wasn't. The correct result was an exception in that case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter quoting "if the position does not correspond to any unit value in the value string, either of the nearest ones can be incremented", so the correct result for the example would be well defined - either days or hours increment - either works, whatever is easier.

Answer (score 0):

It can work if you look at the placeholders in the format string, like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var ts = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
    var format = "hh:mm:ss";
    var unitToIncrement = FindTheUnitAtPos(format, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("original  : {0}", ts);
    Console.WriteLine("increment : {0}", unitToIncrement);
    Console.WriteLine("result    : {0}", ts.Add(unitToIncrement));

    Console.WriteLine();

    ts = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 30, 0);
    format = "dd days hh:mm";
    unitToIncrement = FindTheUnitAtPos(format, 1);
    Console.WriteLine("original  : {0}", ts);
    Console.WriteLine("increment : {0}", unitToIncrement);
    Console.WriteLine("result    : {0}", ts.Add(unitToIncrement));
}

private static TimeSpan FindTheUnitAtPos(string format, int pos)
{
    char c = format[pos];
    switch (c)
    {
        case 's': return new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        case 'm': return new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        case 'h': return new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        case 'd': return new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FteLxB

Comment: Almost! Does not work for non-fixed size formats, e.g. "d days hh:mm" and position 1. (and thats the hard part about it so seemingly simple problem)

Comment: Might suffice to do `if (format.StartsWith("d ")) format = "d" + format;`. Or look for any single-char format specifiers and double them.